# Django- Login not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a page that registers users and then logs them in immediately after. It then redirects them to their profile which is a url that contains their id. There is a model called person, and it has a one-to-one field with User. This is the code for my post method (when someone fills out the register form).

```
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit = False)
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        newperson = person(user=user)
        newperson.save()
        user.save()
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/profiles/' + str(user.person.id))
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

It then runs this function:

```
def loadprof(request, profile_id):
    print(request.user)
    try:
        user = person.objects.get(id=profile_id)
        user_schedules = user.schedules_set.all()
    except person.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("The profile you are looking for does not exist.")
    if request.user.person.id == profile_id:
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user': user, 
            "user_schedules": user_schedules})
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user': user, "user_schedules": 
        user_schedules})
```

It raises a 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'person' error when it runs "if request.user.person.id == profile_id:" in the loadprof function. What is happening? I assume because it is an AnonymousUser, the login function didn't work? I imported the login function correctly and everything, I am very lost. Thank You

Comment: "I imported the login function correctly" -- how did you import it?

Comment: "from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login"

Comment: That's correct. The code you've posted looks ok, I can't spot the problem. You should probably add `login_required` to the `loadprof` view to prevent errors, but that doesn't explain why the `login(request, user)` didn't work.

Comment: I'm new in Django but I doubt how does 'user = form.save(commit = False)' works? does form.save() return user object? In my code I use cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'],
                                password=cd['password'])